# Where should I begin in creating a page to allow authenticated users to submit a short story that will become it's own independent page?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, users

I have installed the most recent version of Drupal on my computer using xampp as the local host.

I would like to allow authenticated users to be able to publish content (ie a short story & accompanying imagine) that would appear on a stand alone page, not like a blog; for example, if a user submits 3 stories, then each story could be accessed independently.
Ultimately, during the submission process I would like the user to identify the category of the story (adventure, romance, sci-fi, etc) that would then appear in the appropriate section of the website.
In my mind it would be similar to a user submitting a recipe on a cooking site. I imagine the submission page would not be dissimilar to the page I'm on now to submit this question.

All of which is to say, where do I begin? What modules will best assist me? Can I develop the submission page and then institute the taxonomy?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this gets you off the ground. Of course you need some more reading/googling.

1. Give users the right to register an account on your site.
2. Create a content type with all the fields you need. You can do this with the built in fields features.
3. Create a role that has the right to create/edit/delete a this content type. This is a drupal core feature as well.
4. Assign a role to this users up on register ([auto assign role module](http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole)).
5. Make sure nice descritptive URLs are created automatically from the node titles (and maybe some fields) ([path auto module](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto))
6. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Start at the library :) .  Drupal is a content management system so it does not create static pages.  It can do what you want right out of the box but may not be doing it the way you expect. Go to admin/content/create content and create a page.  Everything you asked for should be right there.  However, take the time to learn the basics from several excellent Drupal primers out there.  As soon as you do, you will want more to do more!

There is also a lot of help available at this site.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you have suggestions for some primers?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is in the out of the box installation. You might have Views installed, but first you must master the basics.